# Transients question - Understanding the current

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, switches

Consider:

[image]

How can I understand the second part of the question? After I close S2, I have the answers... Why is the expression for after I close S2 given by \$= 0.48 -0.3e^-3t\$?

Comment: What's the steady-state current at t=100s? What is the time constant of an L-R circuit?  Do you know or can you derive the formula for the exponential decay of a simple 1st order L-R system with a given initial condition? What's the component of the current in SW2 due to the source and the 25 ohm resistor?

Answer (score 2):

Very simple.

You'll have a current through sw2 due to the 12V battery limited by the 25 Ohm resistor.

This the + 0.48 component (taking this as a positive current direction)

Then you have the decay of the inductor (current in the opposite direction hence the '-'sign)

The steady state current will be determined by the total resistance (25+15 = 40 ohms) of the circuit and the 12 volt battery  (i.e. 12/40 = 0.3 Amps)

and finally the time constant for the exponential **decay** = T = L/R = 5/15 
 giving you -3t (= -t/T)) as the exponent.

Put them all together to give 0.48 -0.3e^-3t

Comment: I got, thanks veeeeery much it was a great explanation.